# Elasticsearch: Query for document containing two key-value pairs in an array

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I query for a document containing both of the key-value pairs "key1"-"value1" and "key2"-"value2"? I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

I tried the query below but it returns no results even though there should be matching documents. Replacing must with should works though, but then when I put minimum_should_match = 100%, it also doesn't return any results.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attributes",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  [
                    {
                      "match_phrase": {
                        "attributes.key": "key1"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "match_phrase": {
                        "attributes.value": "value1"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  [
                    {
                      "match_phrase": {
                        "attributes.key": "key2"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "match_phrase": {
                        "attributes.value": "value2"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        [
          {
            "match_all": {

            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is how the mapping looks like:

```
{
    "index_name": {
        "mappings": {
            "type_name": {
                "properties": {
                    "attributes": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "key": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "flat"
                            },
                            "value": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "flat"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "nested": {
                        "path": "attributes",
                        "query": {
                           "bool": {
                              "must": [
                                 {
                                    "term": {
                                       "attributes.key": "key1"
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "term": {
                                       "attributes.value": "value1"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "nested": {
                        "path": "attributes",
                        "query": {
                           "bool": {
                              "must": [
                                 {
                                    "term": {
                                       "attributes.key": "key2"
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "term": {
                                       "attributes.value": "value2"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the code I used to test it (I just used the `standard` analyzer, since I didn't know what your `flat` analyzer looks like; so you might have to adjust for that):

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/13b7e2aa4d90bfb2f82787c6a00494ee3343e013

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this experiencing the same issue with Elastic 5 and had to tweak the recommended answer slightly to get it to work as the filtered query has been deprecated.  (was receiving no [query] registered for [filtered]).

With Elastic 5 the following structure solved it for me:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "nested" : {
                        "path": "attributes",
                        "query" : {
                            "bool" : {
                                "must" : [
                                    { "term" : { "attributes.key" : "key1" } },
                                    { "term" : { "attributes.value" : "value1" } }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested" : {
                        "path" : "attributes",
                        "query" : {
                            "bool" : {
                                "must" : [
                                    { "term" : { "attributes.key" : "key2" } },
                                    { "term" : { "attributes.value" : "value2" } }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```